# Como obter valor do índice de maior repetição em uma string em php

Tags: php

**Gostaria de obter o valor do índice de maior repetição em uma string.**

Exemplo da string : `4,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,5,3`.

O resultado deve ser *"1"*, pois ele se repete 5 vezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$array = array(4,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,5,3);
$total = array_count_values($array);
```

Assim, `$total` será um *array* conforme abaixo:

> ```
> $total
> (
>     [1] => 5
>     [2] => 2
>     [3] => 2
>     [4] => 1
>     [5] => 1
> )
> ```